# How can I connect to an RDS MySQL DB from C# using a Certificate Authority?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, amazon-web-services, xamarin.mac

I am building a `Xamarin.Mac` application (**C#**) which needs to connect to an AWS RDS MySQL database.

I have the code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM store", connection))
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
                            reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Where my connection string is of the format:

```
ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1}Uid={2};Pwd={3}";
```

However, I can't seem to connect. Yet, using the same host and credentials via MySqlWorkbench, I can connect just fine. I saw that my RDS instance was build with the setting **Certificate Authority** set to `rds-ca-2015` (there is no option to **not** set it as this).

**How can I connect to this RDS DB using the C# code above?**

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this does **not** have to do with certificate authority as I initially thought.

However, I figured I'd post an answer because it took me a long time to find a solution, and other devs will hopefully find it useful.

So for other developers who are using **Xamarin.Mac** to build an OSX application, you **need** to set your project to use `Xamarin.Mac .NET 4.5 Framework`. This is *not* the default when starting a new OSX project, so you must change it and retarget your packages. Then simply add the NuGet package `MySql.Data` and update your connection code to:

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM store", connection))
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
                        reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2));
                }
            }
        }
```

Works like a charm after that.